# Js Create div into a main div which displays a webpage with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, dom

I have a web page in which, through JavaScript, AJAX and DOM I create a main div with fixed dimensions, where I take inside a web page (a map) through an iframe and then using the coordinates in an array to create many divs (green stars), which should be placed on the map.

At this point, there are 2 problems:

- the first is that the stars are not positioned relatively to the map, but on the whole page, that is, if I have the map div high 744px and a y-coordinate of a point is at 950px star is created on the page web under the map
- the second is that when you scroll the map, points remain motionless. 
  I would that the "stars" were created in relation to the map, and then were generated based on the scroll, remaining in their location on the map.

css:

```
.divLogincss {
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 744px;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.divClk {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color:#00B6E4;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function createElement(tagName, id, className) {
    var elm = document.createElement(tagName);
    if (id) {
        elm.id = id;
    }
    if (className) {
        elm.className = className;
    }
    return elm;
}

function clickmap() {
    var divLogin = createElement('div', 'divLogin', 'divLogincss');
    var objSf = createElement("IFRAME", 'objSf', 'objSfcss'); 

    if (typeof(response.click) === 'undefined' || response.click === null) {
        objSf.setAttribute("src", 'http://'+oDomain );
        objSf.setAttribute("frameBorder", '0' );
        divLogin.appendChild(objSf);
    } else {
        objSf.setAttribute("src", 'http://'+oDomain+response.click[1].paddr);
        objSf.setAttribute("frameBorder", '0' );
        divLogin.appendChild(objSf);
        for (i = 0; i < response.click.length; i++) {
            var divClick = createElement('div', 'divClick', 'divClk');
            var repos = (1000 * parseInt(response.click[i].xpos))/parseInt(response.click[i].winw);
            divClick.setAttribute('style','left: '+repos+'px;top: '+parseInt(response.click[i].ypos)+'px;');
            divLogin.appendChild(divClick);
        }
    }

    return divLogin;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

[image: Scroll trouble]

Comment: Take a look at the Google Maps JavaScript API which gives you the functionality needed for this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Comment: Thanks, but the map is an example, in fact, the website showed it could be any website